# Cutting a $m \times n$ rectangle into $a \times b$ smaller rectangular pieces

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, contest-math, tiling

> How many $a \times b$ rectangular pieces of cardboard can be cut from $m \times n$ rectangular piece of cardboard so that the amount of waste("left over" cardboard) is a minimum?

This question was given to me by my Mathematics Teacher as a "brain teaser".

At first I divided $m \times n$ by $a \times b,$ but then I realized that it is not possible in the given situation, as the "left over" cardboard will also be "divided" among $a \times b$.

Next I tried started thinking it terms of perimeter. I imagined all the $a \times b$ rectangles lying side by side in a "rows and columns" format(sort of a grid), without any space between them, thus forming another rectangle/square. I assumed $\lambda$ rows and $\sigma$ columns of those smaller rectangles. After a bit of calculations, my answer came out as following :

Number of smaller $a \times b $ rectangles  $\geq \sigma \times \lambda$ = $\left(\dfrac {m - m \, mod \, a }{a}\right) \times \left(\dfrac {n-n\, mod \, b}{b}\right).$

**Is my "second" approach correct ?**

Is there any alternate way of tackling this problem?

This might seem a 'vague' question, but **can this problem be generalized to any given shape ?**

Any help will be gratefully acknowledged :).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988934/optimal-box-in-a-box-in-a-boxing

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That does not seem to help a lot ... one answer says Without Loss Of generality assume boxes to be distinct.... By the way is my approach correct ???

Comment: I don't believe there is any known way to calculate this with a direct formula, and BeaitifulArt's link seems to agree.

Comment: @Kaynex Is my approach OK ???

Comment: You've asked twice if your approach is "OK".  I'd say it's a good start, but it leaves a lot of cases untested.  You might imagine a situation where you lay a row of $a\times b$ rectangles length-wise, but then another row turned 90 degrees.  Maybe $3a + 5b = m$, so by laying 3 rows one way and 5 rows the other way, you end up with no waste in the $m$ direction.  The point is that there are infinity minus one things to think about here.

Comment: As to the side question: It may be generalised. "How many circles of radius $r$ fit inside a larger circle of radius $R$?", "How many regular <polygon-name> with side length $l$ fit inside a larger regular <polygon-name> with side length $L$?", and so on. See [Packing problems, at en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems)

Comment: @B.Goddard The problem asks for minimum waste .... So there must be some specific strategy to tackle this question. As far as I think, my approach gives the left-over area in such a way that it can not be further divided into the smaller $a \times b$ rectangles ....

Comment: @Nirbhay I explained why your approach fails.  It can't even distinguish between whether $a\times b$ is better than $b\times a$.  Suppose the large rectangle is $9\times 9$ and the small one is $3\times 2$.  Your method would lay $4$ rows of $3\times 2$'s leaving waste of $9$ square units.  I can beat that by laying $3$ rows of $3\times 2$'s and then one row of $2\times 3$'s leaving only $3$ square units of waste.

Comment: @B.Goddard Any ideas then ???

Comment: @Nirbhay  Lots.  Maybe Bezout's theorem will help.

Comment: @B.Goddard If instead my question was to find/know/whatever the maximum $number$ of smaller rectangles, then would my approach be correct..  Also, besides Bezout's theorem, is there any elementary or pre-college technique/rule/theorem ... that can help ????

Comment: @Nirbhay No, my example above still beats your method.

Comment: @Nirbhay There probably is a general method, but it will involve lots of cases, depending on $a \mod m$, $a \mod n$, $b \mod m$ and $b \mod n$.  You might google "tiling problems".

Comment: It is called [Cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem), in your case 2D with single pattern. Corresponding ILP problem is NP-hard as it seems, approximate knapsack could help.

Comment: @sas Can you suggest an answer for this problem. I you know the answer, then please post it as the answer ....

Answer (score 2):

The approach proposed in the OP may be good, as it gives a waste $W $ of

$$W=(m \mod{a}) \cdot n +  (n \mod { b}) \cdot m - (m \mod { a} ) ( n \mod {b}) $$

that in most cases is distributed along two adjacent sides. For example, let us take a $120\times 100$ rectangle to be filled with $11\times 7$ rectangles. Using the approach of the OP, the waste is

$$W=(120 \mod 11) \cdot 100 + (100 \mod 7) \cdot 120 -  ( 120 \mod 11 )\cdot ( 100 \mod 7) \\ =10 \cdot 100 + 2 \cdot 120 - 10 \cdot 2=320$$

However, I believe that there could be a potentially better strategy. We could assess whether one between $m $ and  $n $ can be expressed as  $ax+by $, where $x$ and $y $ are  integers. If this is the case, we can leave an incomplete region only along a single side of the large rectangle (instead of two). For instance, in the example above, we can note that $120$ can be expressed as $$120=99+21=9 \cdot 11 +3\cdot 7 \,\,\,\,$$ So, dividing the sides equal to $120$ in two parts measuring $99$ and $21$, we can divide the initial rectangle in two rectangles ( $99 \times 100$ and $21 \cdot 100$). The first one can be filled beginning from the side equal to $99$, placing a first sequence of $9$ small rectangles (oriented as $11 \cdot 7$)  to cover  a $99 \times 7 $ area, then another sequence to achieve a $99 \times 14 $ area, and so on, arriving to a $99 \times 98$ area. This leaves a partial waste of $2 \cdot 99=198$. The second one can be filled beginning from the side equal to $21$, placing a first sequence of $3$ small rectangles (oriented as  $7 \cdot 11$) to cover a $21 \times 11$ area, then another sequence to achieve a $21 \times 22 $ area, and so on, arriving to a $21 \times 99 $ area. This leaves a partial waste of $1 \cdot 21=21$. The total waste is $198+21=219$. Generalizing, if we can set $m=ax+by $, the waste with this approach is $$W=ax \cdot (n \mod b) + by \cdot (n \mod a) $$

There are several points to be highligted in this solution. First, this approach should be attempted by considering all possibilities of expressing  $m $ or $n $ as $ax+by $, and choosing the one that minimizes the waste. In the example used before, other two possibilities could be to set $$m=120=2 \cdot 11 + 14 \cdot 7\,\,$$ or $$n=100=4 \cdot 11 + 8 \cdot 7\,\, $$ Using the same procedure, it can be easily shown that these choices lead to wastes of $142$ and $604$, respectively. Among all three possibilities, that leaving $142$ gives the best solution. Second, even if this approach allows a nearly full packing along three sides, it does not always produce a minor waste than the solution suggested in the OP. The case $W=604$ described above is an example of this. Also note that the solution of the OP could be applied after rotating the initial rectangle by $90^o $ to get

$$W=(100 \mod 11) \cdot 120 + (120 \mod 7) \cdot 100 -  ( 100 \mod 11 )\cdot ( 120 \mod 7) \\ =1 \cdot 120 + 1 \cdot 100 - 1 \cdot 10=210$$

which is a better result than that initially obtained. Lastly, 
 note that a "complete" packing  (with no waste) can be obtained only in two scenarios, that is to say 1) $a $ divides $m $ and $b $ divides $n $ (or alternatively $a $ divides $n$ and $b $ divides $m $), 2) both $a $ and $b $ divide one (the same) of $m $ and $n $, for example  $m $, and the other (in this example  $n $) is of the form $n=ax+by \,\,\,$ with $x,y$ integers.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Part_Rett]

A simple example, for $a=2, b=3$, and a few values for $n$ and $m$ shows that the problem 
is not easily approachable, specially in the last configuration.

--- *added*-----

It is in fact a *Cutting Stock Problem* as rightly indicated by @sas, however simplified
by having rectangular and fixed size items.
It is quite an interesting subject, so starting from the sketch above, let's try and establish some facts about,
*without pretending to be rigourous and to provide proofs*.
Premised that we use the following symbols, for the integral and fractional part and for modulus
$$
\begin{gathered}
  x = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\} \hfill \\
  \frac{x}
{t} = \left\lfloor {\frac{x}
{t}} \right\rfloor  + \left\{ {\frac{x}
{t}} \right\} \hfill \\
  x = t\left\lfloor {\frac{x}
{t}} \right\rfloor  + t\left\{ {\frac{x}
{t}} \right\} = t\left\lfloor {\frac{x}
{t}} \right\rfloor  + x\bmod t \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
then

1. *Upper bound for $N$*
   Clearly we must have $N a b \leqslant nm$, i.e.
   $$ \bbox[lightyellow]{ 
   N \leqslant \left\lfloor {\frac{{n\,m}}
   {{a\,b}}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\,\frac{{n\,m/\gcd (nm,ab)}}
   {{a\,b/\gcd (nm,ab)}}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\frac{{n'\,}}
   {{a'}}\,\frac{{m'}}
   {{b'}}} \right\rfloor
    \tag {1}  \\
   }
   $$
   This also indicates an equivalence in the problem when the parameters are scaled so as to keep the ratio $(nm)/(ab)$ constant,
   and that we can always reduce the parameters and get $n$ and $m$ be coprime vs. $a$ and vs. $b$.
   But, geometrically speaking, the down-scaling **looks** to be applicable only if  $max(a',b') \leqslant min(n',m')$.
   An example is given in this sketch
   [image: Part_Rett_3]
2. *Equivalence under rotation, reflection*
   Clearly the problem does not change under rotation or reflection.
3. *"Cross histogram"*
   Consider to take a horizontal scan and to record, per each unit row, the number of layers of horizontal dimension $a$ and $b$ traversed.
   Let's do the same on a vertical scan.
   [image: Part_Rett_2r]
   Clearly, every $b$ counts for a layer of width $a$ in one direction will correspond to $a$ counts for $b$ in the other direction.
   And viceversa.
4. *Conclusions*
   Condensing all the considerations above we are led to claim the following:
   a)  Among the various possible partitions of $m$ and $n$ (in case $n'$, $m'$) as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$,
   with non-negative integral coefficients, as
   $$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
   \left\{ \begin{gathered}
     n = n_{\,a} a + n_{\,b} b + n_{\,r}  \hfill \\
     m = m_{\,a} a + m_{\,b} b + m_{\,r}  \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   \tag {2} }$$
   we shall choose those which, while giving minimal remainder
   ($n_r,m_r$), also assure best symmetry around $n/2$,$m/2$, that is
   $$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
   \left\{ \begin{gathered}
     n_{\,a} a \approx n/2 \approx n_{\,b} b \hfill \\
     m_{\,a} a \approx m/2 \approx m_{\,b} b \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   \tag {3} }$$
   b) Note that the above goal of symmetry is to be achieved globally on $n$ and $m$, so that it happens that we shall compromise
   somehow on one of the parameters, to keep  the best on the other.  When that happens, for the 
   *unbalanced* parameter we are asked to choose two partions on the opposite sides of the symmetry, so that they make an optimal one 
   on average, in case inserting a remainder if necessary (re. to the case $n=4,m=5$ in the first sketch).
   So, practically, we are determining a pair of partitions for each parameter.
   c) The above situation can be faced when $n,m$ are relatively small with respect to $a,b$. When they are much larger than $a,b$
   then a partion (or two on average) close to symmetry can be found for both.

Therefrom a possible strategy seems to be as follows (you can follow the process on one of the sketches given)

- repart one side of the rectangle (e.g. $m$) according to one of its pair of partitions, putting first all the $a$'s, then the remainder, then the $b$'s;
- following the perimeter, repart the contiguous side ($n$), this time starting with the $b$'s;
- pass to next side ($m$), and apply the remaining partition of the pair associated with $m$;
- same for the last side;
- expand the partition of the perimeter towards the inner part, as allowed

From the examples, it **looks that** it is possible to reach $N= \left\lfloor {\frac{{n\,m}}{{a\,b}}} \right\rfloor$ in **"many"** cases.

Comment: @G Cab Which software did you use ????  Do you have any idea how to solve the problem ???

Comment: @Nirbhay I did the sketch by hand, trying to validate a possible approach, which unfortunately does not work for particular values of $m$ and $n$ as shown. However it provides upper and lower bounds: I will add it to my answer, as it might interest you anyway.

Comment: How can you possibly "sketch" that "by hand" ????

Comment: @Nirbhay: by hand on a spreadsheet

Comment: How many $2\times 2$ squares can you fit into a $3\times 3$ square?  Certainly no more than $1$, despite the fact that $\lfloor(9/4)\rfloor=2$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: you are right, thanks for signalling. In this case we cannot reach $\lfloor(9/4)\rfloor=2$. However the process of construction by partition of the perimeter remains valid. I will amend my answer.

Comment: You may have assumed that all rectangles are arranged at right angles to each other; which is not a stipulation of the question.  There will be cases when a diagonally placed rectangle must be part of the solution.

Comment: @RobertFrost: yours is an interesting objection, in fact I did not consider placements other than vert./horiz. . Please indicate an example of a diagonal placement obtaining better results.

Comment: @Nirbhay: thanks for assigning the bounty, although I realize that my answer does not satisfy fully your requirements.

Comment: @GCab No probs.... ^_^

Comment: @GCab I don't have long but... I can imagine a long thin rectangle too long to fit in vertically, but can do so if turned at 45 degrees

Comment: @RobertFrost: yes, that's the case if we admit that $a$ or $b$ can be larger than $n,m$: that opens a quite different scenario.